# Where should you put XSD documentation in order for JAXB to pick them up and put them in Javadoc?

Tags: xml, wsdl, xsd, jaxb, wsdl2java

I am developing a contract first webservice and wish to include the appropriate documentation in the schema so that it is as self descriptive as possible.

What is the best practice to put XSD annotations and documentation such that JAXB picks them up and includes them in the generated Java files as Javadoc? I noticed that some elements and enumeration get the documentation picked up, but some others are not. Is there a specific place I have to put them after each element, complex type definition or WSDL operation in order to have it describing each Class, Element or Method?